# A View on Another View IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to place a View on another view.

I have a VideoPlayerController and I want to paint something on it.

I have another view which has a transparent background and painting code in it.

I want to place this view on the video view.

Have tried various ways for it but not getting trough. Please Help.

I want my View on a Full Screen VideoPlayerController

Is it possible???

Comment: give code that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code for add subview in view.

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]init];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:view];
// OR
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

This view to add your mainview.

Comment: Does `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:view];` add view to the array of subviews?

Comment: I tried your solution but the view is not shown above... It stays below the view on which I am adding it...

Comment: one another idea for you. your view add in viewdidload and that view hide =True and after click on the button that view show (hide=False)

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

What about just:

```
[self.view addSubview:myOtherView];
```

Comment: Well, you will have to add it to your view hierarchy somehow and somewhere.

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    
    [moviePlayerController.view addSubview:canvasView];` This is what I have already done...